# Is it possible to set Metric measurement system across all current user profiles via registry editor?

Tags: registry

as mentioned in the title above.

Is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\International applicable? I'm afraid to adjust the registry without knowing its purpose as warned by many guides, I have tried to research online about International key but to no avail. Appreciate if any help!